# No source available for "realloc() " in Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, realloc

When I debugging my c codes, I am getting this on the realloc line. How can I solve this? I included stdlib.h

Comment: It probably means that the debugger doesn't know where to find the source code (part of glibc) for the `realloc()` function.  Why do you need it?

Comment: But malloc() function works well. I don't know how many word is in a .txt and I need array of words...

Comment: You don't need the source of `realloc()`. The message should be just a warning; you can safely ignore it.

Comment: OP's crash happened in realloc due to memory corruption. Rather than trying to debug realloc (which is not buggy), OP should use valgrind and find the source of the memory corruption.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug libc you need the development libraries

http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/libc6-dev

in a console, type:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

now in practice, you should not need to debug this function, however it would make the error go away.